# Using list comprehension instead of for loop to remove nested lists without removing their elements

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
      lst = [1,2,3,4,[5,6], 7,8,9]
                new_lst = []
                for i in range(len(lst)):
                    if type(lst[i])==list:
                        new_lst.extend(lst[i])
                    else:
                        new_lst.append(lst[i])
                return new_lst
        and the new_lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Is there a way to make this work for [1,2,[3,4,[5,6,[7]]],8,9,10] ?
is it possible to get to work with list comprehension ?

Comment: You might consider using [`more_itertools.collapse`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.collapse).

Comment: For *arbitrarily nested lists*? Probably no sane way

Comment: `fn = lambda lst: (fn(lst[0]) if len(lst) == 1 else ([] if len(lst) == 0 else [vv for v in lst for vv in fn(v)])) if isinstance(lst, list) else [lst]`